# Connecting Django Celery Beat to the correct database

Tags: python, django, postgresql, celery

I am getting started with celery (4.4.7) using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWxYPq7Sc8A&list=PLOLrQ9Pn6caz-6WpcBYxV84g9gwptoN20&index=5). I believe I have set up everything correctly but whenever I run the following command:

```
celery -A myproj beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

I get the error:

```
django.db.utils ProgrammingError :relation "django_celery_beat_periodictask" does not exist
```

I migrated the DB and so the celery beat tables do exist. This closed issue https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/issues/22 is exactly the error I am getting, however, what seems to be the [solution](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results/issues/22#issuecomment-323062892) does not work for me possibly because I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I would check your settings.py file to check what you have set for the celery config.

If this has not been created with postgres then you can use postgres to create the db, user, password and set privledges

Creating user

```
$ sudo -u postgres createuser <username>
```

Creating Database

```
$ sudo -u postgres createdb <dbname>
```

Giving the user a password

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql=# alter user <username> with encrypted password '<password>';
```

Granting privileges on database

```
psql=# grant all privileges on database <dbname> to <username> ;
```